# Force iOS app to open in foreground using private APIs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I'm currently working on a kiosk type application that ***won't be distributed on the App Store***. The device will sometimes need to switch applications to handle some other tasks, but in the case where a user doesn't manually switch back, I need my app to come to the foreground after a set amount of time has passed.

We don't have control over the other apps, so getting them to switch to ours after a timeout isn't possible.

***I know this can't be done through official means***, but I'm asking if anyone knows of a ***private API*** I could call from within a scheduled notification that will foreground my application.

I have a feeling that this cannot be done without a jailbreak due to the sandboxing nature of the apps, as in, there's no way to send a message to whatever service launches apps on the device. Although it ***should*** be possible, as the demo devices in the Apple stores are able to revert back to a demo "screensaver" app if left alone for a while. What are they doing to achieve this?

If there is a jailbreak hack for this to work or a config or something an MDM service could handle, I'd be happy to try that out.

Again, this is for a ***private application*** that ***will not*** be distributed on the App Store. The app will be placed on devices located throughout our building and running on our internal network.

Comment: There isn't a way to do so. However, if you are working on Android OS, there will be solutions.

Comment: The devices in the Apple Store don't run a standard iOS release; they run an Apple Store "special"

Comment: do you want to wake up app or switch to that app

Comment: Switch to that app @MuhammedAzharudheen

Comment: @Raptor Will definitely consider Android if there's no possible way on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: When we make kiosks with tablets, we simply use droid tablets - it becomes much easier.  Would it make your life easier??  If this is a Unity project, it's trivial to build to droid tablets (EVEN FROM YOUR MAC - no need to buy a Windows machine!).  You literally just plug it in with a cable and hit "play" - even if you know nothing about droid! heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Jailbreak you could look at something like AutoLaunch:

> If you use a particular app that seems to crash here and there, then a new free jailbreak tweak called AutoLaunch could be your next best friend. It can automatically re-launch any app that crashes on your device so you don’t have to re-launch it yourself.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/01/08/autolaunch/

Not sure how much control you'd have over wanting to launch regardless of whether it's crashed or not. You might be able to ask the author to provide the source-code or work with him to get your desired result.

**UPDATE:**

It's open source:

https://github.com/chenzhijie/autolaunch

Upon further inspection of the [source](https://github.com/chenzhijie/autolaunch/blob/master/Tweak.xm) it looks like it uses the following to launch the application after a crash:

```
int createSubProcessResult = fork();
if(createSubProcessResult == 0) {
   execl("/usr/bin/open","open",[currentAppBundleId UTF8String],NULL);
}
```

I guess you could roll your own version of Autolaunch and have it wait/subscribe for a remove command that'll launch/switch different apps.

Comment: This is excellent and gives me a starting point and something to work from. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting it as an answer if you like. Glad I could help.

Comment: I'll give it a few more hours, and give this a go in the meantime.